# namespace global function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using ruby on rails 3.1.3 to build my application.
Now, I want to make a global function for every controller in a specific namespace.
(example: I have an admin namespace and I want to create specific function for an admin to check user authorization and change the layout view.)

Where should I place my global function?

Answer (score 0):

You normally mirror the namespace tree in controllers:

```
- application_controller.rb
- admin_controller.rb
- admin
+ - some_admin_controller.rb
```

`ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout "some_default_layout"

  def some_general_method
  end
end
```

`AdminController`:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  layout "admin_layout"

  def some_admin_method
  end
end
```

`SomeAdminController`:

```
class Admin::SomeAdminController < AdminController

  # has access to some_admin_method
end
```

All admin controllers inherit from `AdminController` and have that method then.